# "A problem occurred when trying to delete" in Low Quality Posts

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

When I attempt to "Recommend Deletion" in the Low Quality Posts review queue, I get an error just as I'm moving to the next item in the queue that "A problem occurred when trying to delete".  Why is this the case?  Note that I don't have delete privileges.

Comment: Hmm, do you have a link to the review item? My only guess would be that it was deleted while you were reviewing.

Comment: [His was the first review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3127359), @animuson

Comment: @Shog9: seems to be intermittent, I've just done another one and it seems fine...